# Restrict Years On Month/DatePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Please look at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RWY2X/14/)

What I am after is for the 'Previous' button to be disabled if the year matches the current year but I also want to restrict the 'Next' button to only be enabled for the next year, which if they click it, it then becomes disabled.

I have tried using `minDate: "0"` and `maxDate: "1y"` but they don't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group date" style="width: 200px">
    <input type="text" id="example1" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer"/>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#example1').datepicker
({
    format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    changeYear: true,
    autoclose: true
});
```

**CSS**

```
.datepicker-switch
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

I don't want to have to add years to my code otherwise I will have to update it on a year basis and release my website, so how can this be done without adding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on the solution of J Santosh but fixed the requirements from OP

To limit the datepicker use `startDate` and `endDate`. Pass a calculated date object to options for easy use (no update needed next year)

Reqs: `startDate = this year` and `endDate = this + next year`

Datepicker config:

```
$('#example1').datepicker({
    format: "MM yyyy",
    minViewMode: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), '0', '01'),
    endDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear()+1, '11', '31'),
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RWY2X/28/

PS: `changeYear` is not an existing option

Comment: Thought I had removed the `changeYear` lol but your solution worked great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wanted ? disabling all other years except current year

If yes then use `startDate` and `endDate` options

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RWY2X/21/)

Comment: @J Santosh The next year button is not displayed at when the picker is displayed

Comment: if next button is clicked what you want to disable , for example if current year is 2015 then next button will result in 2016 , which one do you want to disable 2016 or 2017 ?

Comment: @J Santosh When the calendar is displayed, if the year does not equal current year (e.g. 2015) then the 'Next' button should be displayed. If the user then clicks the 'Next' year button, they shouldn't be able to click it again